# Textview, possible to wrap from parent's beginning?

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I have a 2 textviews in a line, TV1 has a short text and TV2 will be text wrapped, here is the displayed text:

```
 TV1  TV2TV2TV2TV2TV2TV2
      TV2TV2TV2TV2
```

What I wanted to do is to have something like:

```
 TV1  TV2TV2TV2TV2TV2TV2
 TV2TV2TV2TV2
```

Please let me know if that's even possible with 2 Textviews

Code:

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"/>

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV2"
            style="@style/text_view_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better make it as single textview appending two text with tab spaced. To show different designing between two text, use spannablestring. SpannabelString can also be used as clickable text. For ex.

```
SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Welcome to Skholingua.com, Click here to visit webpage or here to call me or here get Toast.");
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
          Toast.makeText(context,"yup, this is a ClickableSpan and you have clicked it.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
};
text.setSpan(clickableSpan, 77, 91, 0);
```

Comment: for TV2, I need it link to another activity conditionally, so that's why I want to use two TVs instead of one, I did some research and seems like TV doesn't support partial text link, right?

Comment: You can SpannableString to make clickable text, see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I don't like to use SppannableString because of the calculation of the start/end part will complicate the testing a lot since the strings are dynamic.
For now I guess I'll create two views, one with 1 textview and the other one with 2 textviews, and show/hide them based on the conditions unless I can get a better answer. Thanks

Comment: Using two textviews is much painful than using spannablestring. Always start will be length of the first string and end will be the length of addition of first and second string. That's it bro.